# Clicking Apply LinkedIn button using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on the Apply button on linkedIn but, having a hard time in doing so. I tried to target the id but I noticed that the id always changes when the page reloads.

I've tried:

`browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text() = 'Apply']").click()` and `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type = 'Apply']").click()` but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either of the `xpath`.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space(.)='Apply']").click()
```

OR

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'Apply')]").click()
```

---

**UPADTE:**
It seems synchronization issue induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[normalize-space(.)='Apply']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I received the following Message: element not interactable

Comment: @UmmaromanaSama : It seems synchronization issue. Please check updated answer?